# Cox PH non-proportionality: time-dependent variable?

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

I am performing Cox regression modelling, searching for predictors for various clinical outcomes. Now, based on Schoenfeld residuals test, some of my binary predictors have p-value <0.05 with global p-value also <0.05. This means it violates the proportional hazard assumption / it is a time-dependent variable, am I right?
I tried including tt(predictor) in my model but then cox.zph does not recognize it and I cannot test for Schoenfeld. I also tried including "predictor:time" in my model but then it spits 2 separate predictors "predictor0:time" and "predictor1:time" with no reference group. I don't want to do time splitting as it would not make sense clinically to interpret that variable in different time periods.
In this circumstance, can I just use weighted Cox (cox.phw)? How can I test for goodness of fit with cox.phw? An example plot of weighted cox object:[image]
Mind you; I am a clinician with no strong biostats background, just trying to learn and apply these methods, so please bear that in mind when reading and responding. Thank you!:)

Comment: Can you show the KM of survival for the separate covariates. It's easy for some to visualize "non-proportionality" on the survival scale.

Comment: If the curves are only a "little" non-proportional, you can just use the `robust=TRUE` option to calculate sandwich based errors - i.e. asymptotically correct inference for a difference in survival.

Answer (score 1):

It's important in this case is to look at smoothed plots of scaled Schoenfeld residuals as a function of time for the predictors in question. That's true for several reasons.

First, with a large number of events you might find "statistically significant" violations of proportional hazards (PH) that are of small magnitude. You don't know how big a problem you have until you look.

Second, those plots suggest specific forms for the time dependence of the regression coefficients. The ["time dependent" vignette](https://cran.r%60surv-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) illustrates that in Section 4.

Third, if you then choose to model a time dependence with the `tt()` functionality, as you note you can't then use `cox.zph()`.* You can, however, plot the form of the resulting `tt()` function atop the original plot of scaled Schoenfeld residuals to see how well it works, as demonstrated in the last plot in Section 4 of the vignette. Just as you are unlikely in practice to get data that perfectly follow a normal distribution, you are unlikely to get perfect PH. With such a plot, you can apply your knowledge of the subject matter to asses whether the failure of PH is large enough to matter.

In terms of using the [`coxphw` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=coxphw), be careful that you aren't throwing away important information about the association of the covariate with outcome over time. In a standard Cox model that fails PH, you get event-weighted average hazard ratios that run a risk of bias. The `coxphw()` function seeks to remove that bias. If you aren't specifying an explicit function of time with that function, you are *accepting the failure* of PH (so there's no need to test for it) and getting a less-biased estimate of an "average" hazard ratio. But what if the change of hazard over time is clinically important, as with the Karnofsky score in Section 4 of the time-dependent vignette?

You can specify functions of time for covariates with `coxphw()`, and its [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxphw/vignettes/jss_2018_example_code.html) seems to provide code for a `cox.zph()` type of analysis for such models. It's based, however, on code adapted from Version 2.37-4 of the `survival` package and I don't know whether it fixes the error* with time-dependent coefficients.

Finally, don't feel limited to Cox PH models. Accelerated failure time (AFT) models (e.g., log-normal, fit by `survreg()` in the `survival` package) assume covariate-associated expansions/contractions of the time axis instead of proportional hazards. Such a model might fit well if PH doesn't hold in your Cox model. (Unless it's a Weibull model, a parametric AFT model necessarily can't have PH.) Aalen additive models (`aareg()` function) fit both the baseline hazard and coefficients as functions of time; whether that extreme flexibility is a blessing or a curse depends on your data and how carefully you interpret the model.

---

*According to the [NEWS document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/news.html) of the survival package, you were able to use `cox.zph()` on models containing a `tt()` term in versions prior to 3.1-2, but the results were wrong. Keep that in mind if you find such plots in your searching for answers.